# Как получить по координатам название местоположения Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Как, зная координаты, получить название местоположения в Google Maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо использовать обратный геокодинг. Пример на JS из официальной документации ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding ):

```
// Initialize the map.
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 40.72, lng: -73.96}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodePlaceId(geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });
}

// This function is called when the user clicks the UI button requesting
// a reverse geocode.
function geocodePlaceId(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  var placeId = document.getElementById('place-id').value;
  geocoder.geocode({'placeId': placeId}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: основная информация должна присутствовать в тексте ответа, а ссылка может лишь служить источником дополнительных сведений.